# Insert VARIANT type from Pandas into Snowflake

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to insert data from a Pandas dataframe into a table in Snowflake, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it properly. To start with, I have a created a table in Snowflake that has some columns of type `VARIANT`. For example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
    mydatabase.myschema.results(
        DATE date, 
        PRODUCT string, 
        PRODUCT_DETAILS variant, 
        ANALYSIS_META variant,
        PRICE float
)
```

Then in Pandas, I have a dataframe like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
record = {'DATE': '2020-11-05',
 'PRODUCT': 'blue_banana',
 'PRODUCT_DETAILS': "{'is_blue': True, 'is_kiwi': nan}",
 'ANALYSIS_META': "None",
 'PRICE': 13.02}
df = pd.DataFrame(record, index=[0])
```

As you see, I've encoded `VARIANT` columns as strings, as that's what I understood from the [`snowflake-connector` documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html#snowflake-to-pandas-data-mapping), that a Snowflake `VARIANT` type maps to `str` dtype in Pandas and vice-versa.

So, what I've tried to far is the following:

```py
from snowflake.connector import pandas_tools

pandas_tools.write_pandas(
                conn=conn,
                df=df,
                table_name="results",
                schema="myschema",
                database="mydatabase")
```

And this does work, returning

```sh
(True,
 1,
 1,
 [('czeau/file0.txt', 'LOADED', 1, 1, 1, 0, None, None, None, None)])
```

However, the results I get in Snowflake are not of the proper `VARIANT` type. The field `ANALYSIS_META` is correctly `NULL`, but the field `PRODUCT_DETAILS` is of type `str`. See:
[image]

(also, for example this query throws an error:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.RESULTS
WHERE PRODUCT_DETAILS:is_blue -- should work for json/variant fields
```

So with all that, my question is: how should I properly format my Pandas dataframe in order to insert he `VARIANT` fields correctly as nested fields into a Snowflake table? I thought that casting a dictionary into a string would do the trick, but apparently it doesn't work as I expected. What I am missing here?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting from `SELECT * FROM
MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.RESULTS`?

Comment: @demircioglu It says `SQL compilation error: Invalid data type [VARIANT] for predicate [GET(TESTING.PRODUCT_DETAILS, 'is_blue')]`

Comment: Try this, should work `SELECT * FROM
MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.RESULTS
WHERE parse_json(PRODUCT_DETAILS):is_blue`

Comment: @demircioglu I'm still getting the same error as above (`SQL compilation error: Invalid data type [VARIANT] for predicate [GET(PARSE_JSON(TO_CHAR(TESTING.PRODUCT_DETAILS)), 'is_blue')]`), but even if it worked, I'm interested in making sure the type is properly inserted as `VARIANT`. Some other tables in Snowflake that I can see are correctly inserted as `VARIANT` type are highlighted blue and you can click on the values when you preview, as well as extract the nested subfields with the `:` notation. I would like to achieve that without having to cast into `json` again when selecting.

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation, I found the following solution to work:

**1. Ensure that the columns are json-compliant**

The key here is that `json.dumps` will transform your data to the right format (the right quotations, representation of `null` and such).

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
record = {'DATE': '2020-11-05',
 'PRODUCT': 'blue_banana',
 'PRODUCT_DETAILS': json.dumps({'is_blue': True, 'is_kiwi': None}),
 'ANALYSIS_META': json.dumps(None),
 'PRICE': 13.02}
df = pd.DataFrame(record, index=[0])
```

**2. Ensure you use `parse_json` and `INSERT` iteratively**

Instead of using `write_pandas` as tried originally, we can `INSERT` into the table row by row, making sure to specify `parse_json` on the columns of desired `VARIANT` type, while also encoding the value as a string (by putting `'` marks around it). The caveat is that this solution would be very slow if you have large amounts of data.

```py
sql = """INSERT INTO MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.RESULTS
SELECT
 to_date('{DATE}'),
 '{PRODUCT}',
 parse_json('{PRODUCT_DETAILS}'),
 parse_json('{ANALYSIS_META}'),
 {PRICE}
"""
### CREATE A SNOWFLAKE CONN...

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    conn.cursor().execute(sql.format(**dict(r)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems coming together here. Firstly, the syntax for inserting variants is a bit odd. Secondly, it's important to realise that single quotes `'` and double quotes `"` are not the same in terms of Snowflake (or SQL in general?).

### Problem statement

Instead of a pandas dataframe, we could also solve this for a dictionary first. It will be straightforward to extend it to a row in a pandas dataframe.

The goal is to write this query:

```
"""
INSERT INTO mydatabase.myschema.results (
     date, product, product_details, analysis_meta, price
)
SELECT
    '2018-01-01',
    'my_new_products',
    parse_json('{"is_blue": true, "is_kiwi": null}'),
    parse_json('{}'),
    13.02
"""
```

To achieve this, you have to make sure that the `"` and `'` don"t get mixed up and that the dictionary values are wrapped in `"parse_json"`.

---

### Proposed solution

A general solution could be based on (un)zipping the items in `record` and manipulating them a bit along the way. First, we need a function that will process our (to be inserted) values, based on their data type:

```
def process_val(v) -> str:
   """ Wrap dicts and string values for SQL INSERT statement """
   if isinstance(v, dict):
       return f"parse_json({json.dumps(v)})"
   elif isinstance(v, str):
       return f"'{v}'"
   else:
       return v
```

If you stumble upon new types of values, you could add them `process_val()`. We can use `process_val()` while joining together the processed values:

```
def create_insert_statement(table: str, record: Dict[str, Any]) -> str:
    columns, values = zip(*record.items())

    col_string = ", ".join(columns)
    val_string = ", ".join(process_val(v) for v in values)

    return f"INSERT INTO {table} ({col_string}) SELECT {val_string}"
```

You can now iteratively insert your records:

```
table = "mydatabase.myschema.results"

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    query = create_insert_statement(table=table, record=dict(r))
    conn.cursor().execute(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still use `write_pandas` then first format the string as json via `json.dumps()` and then use additional sql call where you will apply `parse_json` on the uploaded column via

`UPDATE table SET product_details=parse_json(product_details);`